# Change logo on scroll Shopify dawn theme

Tags: javascript, css, liquid, shopify-template

I would like to know how to use javascript to change the source of the logo image after scrolling a certain amount in shopify dawn theme.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't tested but you can do it like this

```
const heightToAdjustElement = 350;
const newLogoSrc = "cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0551/9242/0441/files/Dawn_logo_90x.png"

window.addEventListener('scroll', (event) => {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > heightToAdjustElement || document.documentElement.scrollTop > heightToAdjustElement) {
  document.querySelector('.header__heading-logo').src = newLogoSrc;
}
});
```

You should create a new section setting for the alternative logo too and link the js variable newLogoSrc with what ever that is something like {{ section.settings.alternative_logo }}

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll_event

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop

Answer (score 1):

Try these CSS code

```
  .shopify-section-header-sticky .header__heading-link{
    background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0678/1567/0065/files/GrowGen-web-logo-2021_new_1_2.png?v=1668927470&width=250");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 250px;
    height: 90px;
 
    }

  .shopify-section-header-sticky img{
    display:none;
  }
```